# hash map no viable overloaded '='

Tags: c++

```
public:
    typedef ics::pair<KEY,T>   Entry;
    typedef int (*hashfunc) (const KEY& a);

private:
  int (*hash)(const KEY& k);      //Hashing function used (from template or constructor)
  enum bin_state {bs_empty, bs_occupied, bs_was_occupied};
  Entry* map       = nullptr;    //Entry array
  bin_state* state = nullptr;    //bin_state[] describes the state of map[i]
  double load_threshold;         //used/bins <= load_threshold
  int bins         = 1;          //# bins in array (should start at 1 so hash_compress doesn't % 0)
  int used         = 0;          //Cache for number of key->value pairs in the hash table
  int mod_count    = 0;          //For sensing concurrent modification


  //Helper methods
  int   hash_compress      (const KEY& key)  const;  //hash function ranged to [0,bins-1]
  int   find_key           (const KEY& key)  const;  //Returns index to key's bin or -1
  int   next_unoccupied    (int bin)         const;  //this bin or next beyond that is unoccupied

  void  ensure_load_threshold(int new_used);                 //Reallocate if load_factor > load_threshold



HashOpenMap<KEY,T,thash>::HashOpenMap(double the_load_threshold, int (*chash)(const KEY& k)): hash(thash != (hashfunc)undefinedhash<KEY> ? thash : chash), load_threshold(the_load_threshold)
{
    if (hash == (hashfunc)undefinedhash<KEY>)
        throw TemplateFunctionError("HashMap::default constructor: neither specified");
    if (thash != (hashfunc)undefinedhash<KEY> && chash != (hashfunc)undefinedhash<KEY> && thash != chash)
        throw TemplateFunctionError("HashMap::default constructor: both specified and different");

    map = new Entry[bins];
    for (int b=0; b<bins; ++b)
        map[b] =  new bin_state[];

}
```

I am new to c++. I am currently writing the Constructors for the HashOpenMap. For the above code, I got the following error:

```
 no viable overloaded '='
    map[b] =  new bin_state[];
```

any idea how to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: `Entry` and `bin_state` are quite different ...

Comment: `bin_state` is an enum, `bin_state[]` is an array of enums. What's `Entry`?

Comment: I added the code that defines Entry...

Comment: In line `map[b] =  new bin_state[];` what is the size of array `bin_state`? I think the problem is with size of array.

Comment: I am not sure...

Comment: If `map` is an `Entry*`, then a `map[i]` is an `Entry`. And you are trying to assign something completely different to `map[i]`. Did you want to assign something to `state` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you instantiate the same type as the target array element

```
map[b] =  new Entry{};
```

Also, consider not using `new`/`delete` in C++. Or raw C arrays.

Comment: Hi, do you mean map[b] =  new Entry[]; ? I tried it and it still produces the same error.

Comment: Whoops. I must have missed my morning coffee. There were _two_ typing mistakes in one line. Sorry!